# Data manipulation with DPLYR using multiple ID columns and then value sums from various rows depending on categories. Values are in a single column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

So I have a dataframe with a couple hundred thousand rows that looks like this:

[image: Count Data across a table]

The goal is trying to create columns for each category - SEX=M, SEX=F, RACE=WHITE, RACE=BLACK, RACE=AMERICAN INDIAN/ALASKA NATIVE, RACE=ASIAN OR PACIFIC ISLANDER, RACE=UNKNOWN, HISPANIC_FLAG=0, HISPANIC_FLAG=1
where the values for each column would be the sum of the COUNT column for each category.

Currently for each SEX=M we have it broken out across race and hispanic flag, and I want that summed, and similarly I want that for SEX=M, and then I am trying to sum RACE=White, RACE=Black, etc. in a similar manner (that ignores SEX=M, so it just aggregates it off its own column).

Then in each row I need a unique identifier. I am trying to have only one FIPS/YEAR/ONE/TWO/THREE/etc. be my unique identifiers (notice how ONE/TWO/THREE/etc. are the same as long as FIPS/YEAR are the same).

I have been trying to work with some combination of pivot_wider() and have tried both the names_from and values_from methods:

```
my_pivot = my_sf %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from =c("SEX", "RACE_RECODE_W_B_AI_API", "HISPANIC_FLAG"), values_from="COUNT")
```

and this one which seemed to create ~4500 new rows

```
my_pivot = my_sf %>%
 pivot_wider(id_cols=c("FIPS","YEAR", "ONE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR", "FIVE"), names_from =c("SEX", "RACE_RECODE_W_B_AI_API", "HISPANIC_FLAG"), values_from= "COUNT")
```

I have also tried some aggregates that I can get to work for one column but not for all of them. Is there a quick and easy way to do this in dplyr or tidyr that I'm missing? If it helps, I am also coding the NAs in this as 0's sometimes, but that still doesn't seem to make much of a difference. Thanks!

Working on getting the dput output in here, with the structure included it is ~60k characters long with 100 values and even with just 40 values it's at ~45k chars, so I just ahve this list:

```
structure(list(X1 = c(171, 188, 205, 222, 239, 256, 273, 290, 
307, 324, 341, 358, 375, 392, 409, 426, 443, 460, 477, 494, 681, 
698, 715, 732, 749, 766, 783, 800, 817, 834, 851, 868, 885, 902, 
919, 936, 953, 970, 987, 1004, 1191, 1208, 1225, 1242, 1259, 
1276, 1293, 1310, 1327, 1344, 1361, 1378, 1395, 1412, 1429, 1446, 
1463, 1480, 1497, 172, 189, 206, 223, 240, 257, 274, 291, 308, 
325, 342, 359, 376, 393, 410, 427, 444, 461, 478, 495, 682, 699, 
716, 733, 750, 767, 784, 801, 818, 835, 852, 869, 886, 903, 920, 
937, 954, 971, 988, 1005, 1192), FIPS = c(6001, 6001, 6001, 6001, 
6001, 6001, 6001, 6001, 6001, 6001, 6001, 6001, 6001, 6001, 6001, 
6001, 6001, 6001, 6001, 6001, 6013, 6013, 6013, 6013, 6013, 6013, 
6013, 6013, 6013, 6013, 6013, 6013, 6013, 6013, 6013, 6013, 6013, 
6013, 6013, 6013, 6041, 6041, 6041, 6041, 6041, 6041, 6041, 6041, 
6041, 6041, 6041, 6041, 6041, 6041, 6041, 6041, 6041, 6041, 6041, 
6001, 6001, 6001, 6001, 6001, 6001, 6001, 6001, 6001, 6001, 6001, 
6001, 6001, 6001, 6001, 6001, 6001, 6001, 6001, 6001, 6013, 6013, 
6013, 6013, 6013, 6013, 6013, 6013, 6013, 6013, 6013, 6013, 6013, 
6013, 6013, 6013, 6013, 6013, 6013, 6013, 6041), SEX = c("M", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M"), RACE = c("White", "White", 
"Black", "Black", "American Indian/Alaska Native", "American Indian/Alaska Native", 
"Asian or Pacific Islander", "Asian or Pacific Islander", "Unknown", 
"Unknown", "White", "White", "Black", "Black", "American Indian/Alaska Native", 
"American Indian/Alaska Native", "Asian or Pacific Islander", 
"Asian or Pacific Islander", "Unknown", "Unknown", "White", "White", 
"Black", "Black", "American Indian/Alaska Native", "American Indian/Alaska Native", 
"Asian or Pacific Islander", "Asian or Pacific Islander", "Unknown", 
"Unknown", "White", "White", "Black", "Black", "American Indian/Alaska Native", 
"American Indian/Alaska Native", "Asian or Pacific Islander", 
"Asian or Pacific Islander", "Unknown", "Unknown", "White", "White", 
"Black", "Black", "American Indian/Alaska Native", "American Indian/Alaska Native", 
"Asian or Pacific Islander", "Asian or Pacific Islander", "Unknown", 
"Unknown", "White", "White", "Black", "Black", "American Indian/Alaska Native", 
"American Indian/Alaska Native", "Asian or Pacific Islander", 
"Asian or Pacific Islander", "Unknown", "White", "White", "Black", 
"Black", "American Indian/Alaska Native", "American Indian/Alaska Native", 
"Asian or Pacific Islander", "Asian or Pacific Islander", "Unknown", 
"Unknown", "White", "White", "Black", "Black", "American Indian/Alaska Native", 
"American Indian/Alaska Native", "Asian or Pacific Islander", 
"Asian or Pacific Islander", "Unknown", "Unknown", "White", "White", 
"Black", "Black", "American Indian/Alaska Native", "American Indian/Alaska Native", 
"Asian or Pacific Islander", "Asian or Pacific Islander", "Unknown", 
"Unknown", "White", "White", "Black", "Black", "American Indian/Alaska Native", 
"American Indian/Alaska Native", "Asian or Pacific Islander", 
"Asian or Pacific Islander", "Unknown", "Unknown", "White"), 
    HISPANIC_FLAG = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
    1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
    0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
    1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
    1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 
    0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0), YEAR = c(2000, 2000, 2000, 
    2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
    2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
    2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
    2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
    2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
    2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 
    2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 
    2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 
    2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 
    2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001), COUNT = c(1784, 
    244, 499, 7, 6, 1, 417, 0, 56, 8, 1675, 263, 470, 4, 6, 0, 
    395, 2, 36, 1, 1649, 129, 171, 1, 6, 0, 148, 1, 18, 2, 1678, 
    161, 149, 4, 7, 0, 180, 2, 18, 5, 632, 18, 17, 2, 0, 0, 19, 
    0, 4, 0, 581, 27, 12, 1, 3, 0, 23, 0, 1, 1732, 265, 495, 
    1, 4, 0, 399, 1, 41, 2, 1635, 227, 439, 2, 6, 0, 421, 1, 
    36, 5, 1721, 153, 176, 3, 9, 0, 180, 1, 27, 3, 1672, 158, 
    181, 3, 4, 0, 212, 2, 24, 2, 671), ONE = c(290.4, 290.4, 
    290.4, 290.4, 290.4, 290.4, 290.4, 290.4, 290.4, 290.4, 290.4, 
    290.4, 290.4, 290.4, 290.4, 290.4, 290.4, 290.4, 290.4, 290.4, 
    2940, 2940, 2940, 2940, 2940, 2940, 2940, 2940, 2940, 2940, 
    2940, 2940, 2940, 2940, 2940, 2940, 2940, 2940, 2940, 2940, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 430.2, 430.2, 430.2, 430.2, 430.2, 430.2, 
    430.2, 430.2, 430.2, 430.2, 430.2, 430.2, 430.2, 430.2, 430.2, 
    430.2, 430.2, 430.2, 430.2, 430.2, 1555.1, 1555.1, 1555.1, 
    1555.1, 1555.1, 1555.1, 1555.1, 1555.1, 1555.1, 1555.1, 1555.1, 
    1555.1, 1555.1, 1555.1, 1555.1, 1555.1, 1555.1, 1555.1, 1555.1, 
    1555.1, NA), TWO = c(16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 
    16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 92.8, 92.8, 92.8, 
    92.8, 92.8, 92.8, 92.8, 92.8, 92.8, 92.8, 92.8, 92.8, 92.8, 
    92.8, 92.8, 92.8, 92.8, 92.8, 92.8, 92.8, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    83.5, 83.5, 83.5, 83.5, 83.5, 83.5, 83.5, 83.5, 83.5, 83.5, 
    83.5, 83.5, 83.5, 83.5, 83.5, 83.5, 83.5, 83.5, 83.5, 83.5, 
    16.2, 16.2, 16.2, 16.2, 16.2, 16.2, 16.2, 16.2, 16.2, 16.2, 
    16.2, 16.2, 16.2, 16.2, 16.2, 16.2, 16.2, 16.2, 16.2, 16.2, 
    NA), THREE = c(45.3, 45.3, 45.3, 45.3, 45.3, 45.3, 45.3, 
    45.3, 45.3, 45.3, 45.3, 45.3, 45.3, 45.3, 45.3, 45.3, 45.3, 
    45.3, 45.3, 45.3, 802.8, 802.8, 802.8, 802.8, 802.8, 802.8, 
    802.8, 802.8, 802.8, 802.8, 802.8, 802.8, 802.8, 802.8, 802.8, 
    802.8, 802.8, 802.8, 802.8, 802.8, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 64.2, 
    64.2, 64.2, 64.2, 64.2, 64.2, 64.2, 64.2, 64.2, 64.2, 64.2, 
    64.2, 64.2, 64.2, 64.2, 64.2, 64.2, 64.2, 64.2, 64.2, 1717.7, 
    1717.7, 1717.7, 1717.7, 1717.7, 1717.7, 1717.7, 1717.7, 1717.7, 
    1717.7, 1717.7, 1717.7, 1717.7, 1717.7, 1717.7, 1717.7, 1717.7, 
    1717.7, 1717.7, 1717.7, NA), FOUR = c(27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 
    27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 
    1258.5, 1258.5, 1258.5, 1258.5, 1258.5, 1258.5, 1258.5, 1258.5, 
    1258.5, 1258.5, 1258.5, 1258.5, 1258.5, 1258.5, 1258.5, 1258.5, 
    1258.5, 1258.5, 1258.5, 1258.5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.7, 0.7, 
    0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 
    0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 105.3, 105.3, 105.3, 105.3, 
    105.3, 105.3, 105.3, 105.3, 105.3, 105.3, 105.3, 105.3, 105.3, 
    105.3, 105.3, 105.3, 105.3, 105.3, 105.3, 105.3, NA), FIVE = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 
    20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 8.7, 8.7, 8.7, 8.7, 8.7, 8.7, 8.7, 8.7, 8.7, 
    8.7, 8.7, 8.7, 8.7, 8.7, 8.7, 8.7, 8.7, 8.7, 8.7, 8.7, NA
    )), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Output would look something like

```
structure(list(FIPS = c(6001, 6001, 6001, 6001, 6001, 6001, 6001, 
6001, 6001, 6001, 6001, 6001, 6001, 6001, 6001, 6001, 6001, 6013, 
6013, 6013, 6013, 6013, 6013, 6013, 6013, 6013, 6013, 6013, 6013, 
6013, 6013, 6013, 6013, 6013), YEAR = c(2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 
2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 
2015, 2016, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 
2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016), M = c(3022, 
2940, 2924, 2800, 2872, 2864, 2945, 3143, 3042, 3156, 3165, 3113, 
3127, 3242, 3153, 3177, 3299, 2125, 2273, 2190, 2311, 2282, 2340, 
2409, 2539, 2561, 2602, 2592, 2716, 2746, 2614, 2557, 2702, 2481
), White = c(3966, 3859, 3973, 3734, 3625, 3664, 3812, 4040, 
3961, 4009, 4032, 3938, 3911, 4159, 3935, 3946, 4044, 3617, 3704, 
3674, 3698, 3658, 3778, 3895, 3965, 4016, 4051, 4105, 4184, 4198, 
4000, 4133, 4162, 3910), Non_Hispanic = c(5344, 5208, 5323, 5109, 
5150, 5163, 5282, 5588, 5561, 5705, 5616, 5610, 5603, 5841, 5690, 
5885, 5862, 4024, 4206, 4126, 4155, 4189, 4249, 4397, 4441, 4502, 
4487, 4676, 4832, 4849, 4673, 4741, 4789, 4514), Hispanic = c(530, 
504, 594, 526, 553, 593, 659, 617, 651, 656, 721, 740, 751, 767, 
847, 772, 858, 300, 323, 348, 369, 359, 406, 417, 467, 510, 527, 
528, 555, 543, 556, 586, 645, 639), Black = c(980, 937, 950, 
933, 980, 995, 967, 980, 1001, 1018, 983, 988, 1047, 973, 972, 
954, 945, 325, 363, 385, 382, 424, 417, 421, 411, 479, 438, 499, 
491, 494, 513, 479, 499, 465), American_Indian = c(13, 10, 10, 
9, 22, 19, 16, 20, 20, 22, 20, 25, 22, 25, 22, 17, 25, 13, 13, 
10, 14, 9, 12, 17, 7, 8, 12, 15, 8, 17, 14, 32, 29, 14), Asian = c(814, 
822, 935, 880, 989, 952, 1027, 1095, 1179, 1240, 1199, 1291, 
1279, 1342, 1480, 1610, 1539, 331, 395, 360, 366, 366, 405, 428, 
495, 473, 457, 491, 546, 574, 590, 591, 655, 650), Unknown = c(101, 
84, 49, 79, 87, 126, 119, 70, 51, 72, 103, 108, 95, 109, 128, 
130, 167, 38, 54, 45, 64, 91, 43, 53, 30, 36, 56, 94, 158, 109, 
112, 92, 89, 114), F = c(2852, 2772, 2993, 2835, 2831, 2892, 
2996, 3062, 3170, 3205, 3172, 3237, 3227, 3366, 3384, 3480, 3421, 
2199, 2256, 2284, 2213, 2266, 2315, 2405, 2369, 2451, 2412, 2612, 
2671, 2646, 2615, 2770, 2732, 2672), ONE = c(290.4, 430.2, 226.7, 
173.7, 42.7, 276.7, 494.7, 256.8, 257.6, 29.3, 192.3, 7.6, 173.3, 
31.7, 54.7, 9.4, 41, 2940, 1555.1, 1453.5, 784.4, 669.9, 501.9, 
1419.8, 340, 425.5, 674.3, 451.8, 543.2, 86.1, 511.3, 291.4, 
290.5, 600.7), TWO = c(16, 83.5, 48.4, 28.9, 29.4, 20.7, 22.6, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 0.5, 4.8, NA, 1.2, 1.6, NA, 92.8, 16.2, 61.2, 
54.2, 11.7, 128.4, 37, 97.2, 83.2, 57.2, 204.5, 94.1, 67.7, 18.6, 
19.5, 33.1, 8.2), THREE = c(45.3, 64.2, 8, 3.1, 0.9, 5.2, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 802.8, 1717.7, 329.8, 
69.8, 29.8, 407.1, 490.8, 601.9, 674.1, 345.5, 16.3, 242.7, 77.6, 
4.7, 85.5, NA, 308), FOUR = c(27, 0.7, 17.1, 130, 89.3, 53.3, 
65, 99.6, 108.6, NA, 13, 15.4, 4.7, NA, 28.9, 1.2, NA, 1258.5, 
105.3, 1106.6, 683.4, 850, 915, 636.4, 995.2, 1580.9, 678.6, 
194.9, 440.3, 758.2, 401.4, 862.4, 511.6, 387.8), FIVE = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 3.9, NA, 11.9, NA, NA, NA, NA, 15.5, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 1.5, 20, 8.7, 2.2, NA, 1.8, 4.1, 5.6, 26.9, 0.7, 38.5, 91.5, 
51.2, 1.5, 12.7, 56.8, 27.8, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -34L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: if you use `dput(head(yourdata, 100))` that will give us the first 100 rows in a useable format so we can troubleshoot- "other Mike"

Comment: The `dput` you supplied doesn't match the screenshot of the data you provided... and your expected output is very hard to determine. It's possible to do everything that you've listed here, but if you would like the help, you'll need to focus on making everything clearer. Your data has variables like `BROMOXYNIL` and `RACE_RECODE_W_B_AI_API`.

Comment: Give the above a try - thanks for letting me know how that would make it difficult

Comment: @ThatOneDudeMike the sample data is much better, but what should your final data look like?

Comment: I think the output should be similar to what it is above (this output is based on the first 1000 rows, but the top few rows will be what the output would be for the first 100 rows given above).

Comment: edited post below let me know if that helps or not !

Answer (score 0):

If you want one row per fips and those 5 other variables this code might work. This code will create a unique row based on FIPS and columns one -five, and then for each level of the variables on the right side it will make a column for each variable in the `value.var` argument. For example for when race = white it will have two columns one for count_white value and one for the x1_white value. you can remove variables from any one of the parts below to get different rows/columns/values in the data.

```
library(data.table)


df2 <- dcast(
  setDT(df)
  , FIPS +ONE+TWO+THREE+FOUR+FIVE ~ SEX +RACE+HISPANIC_FLAG+YEAR
  ,value.var = c("COUNT","X1" ))
```

Comment: This is a method that also seems to generates hundreds of columns for me, unfortunately. It expands my dataset from being just a few columns wide to 517 columns.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a solution from one of my colleagues that broke out the data and rejoined it where df is the original csv

```
df_other_vars = df %>% 
  select(-SEX, -RACE,
         -HISPANIC_FLAG, -COUNT) %>% 
  distinct()
​
#now carve out the demographic columns
df_demographics = df %>% 
  select(FIPS, YEAR, SEX, RACE,
         HISPANIC_FLAG, COUNT, POPULATION)
​
#recast Hispanic flag as factor
df_demographics$HISPANIC_FLAG = as.factor(df_demographics$HISPANIC_FLAG)
​
#pivot longer to get sex, race and hispanic flag all in one column
df_demographics = df_demographics %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(SEX, RACE, HISPANIC_FLAG), 
               names_to = "STATUS")
​
​
#delete the STATUS column and pivot wider on the "value" column

df_demog_wide = df_demographics %>% 
  select(-STATUS) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = value, 
              values_from = COUNT,
              values_fn = sum) 
​
#rename the Hispanic columns
df_demog_wide = df_demog_wide %>% 
  rename(COUNT_NON_HISPANIC = COUNT_0,
         COUNT_HISPANIC = COUNT_1)
​
#merge everything together: 
df_merged = left_join(df_demog_wide, df_other_vars, by = c("FIPS", "YEAR"))
```